# How to first show an element, then perform a function to change the style of this element vue.js

Tags: vue.js

When the button is clicked, the onclick event is triggered and the function is executed

```
descriptionShown: function (num) {
                if (this.visibleNumber === num) {
                    this.isShown = !this.isShown;  
                } else {
                    this.isShown = true;
                    this.visibleNumber = num;
                }

                 if(this.isShown)
                     this.textareaResize(num);
            },
```

after isShown = true, the textarea component should be redrawn, since there is
v-if="{{ newRecord.originalRecordId }} == visibleNumber && isShown"

```
<template v-if="{{ newRecord.originalRecordId }} == visibleNumber && isShown">
                            <ul class="list-group" :style="{ display: 'block' }" >
                                <li class="list-group-item"><textarea id="textarea-{{ newRecord.originalRecordId }}" readonly>{{ newRecord.originalRecordText }}</textarea></li>
                            </ul>
                        </template>
                        <template v-else>
                            <ul class="list-group" :style="{ display: 'none' }" >
                                <li class="list-group-item"><textarea id="textarea-{{ newRecord.originalRecordId }}" readonly>{{ newRecord.originalRecordText }}</textarea></li>
                            </ul>
                        </template>
```

How do I make it so that the redraw occurs first(via v-if), and then the function to change the size of the textarea is executed? And then it turns out that first there is a change in size(0 to 0), then only the element is displayed

Comment: `v-if="{{ newRecord.originalRecordId }} == visibleNumber && isShown"` is invalid. `v-if="newRecord.originalRecordId == visibleNumber && isShown"` would be correct. Also, keep clear of loose comparisons (use `===` instead of `==`). It will save you a lot of time and head-aches.

Comment: On a different note, rather than asking about changing the low-level logic of Vue components (which only few know much about), why don't you ask about the actual functionality you're trying to achieve, showing what you tried and why you think it should work? Running some code before some other code can't be your final goal. Please explain the functionality you are trying to achieve through code.